# "Double or nothing" - Seinfeld season 6

Tags: american-english, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, theater

In "[The Diplomat's Club](http://seinfeldscripts.com/TheDiplomatClub.htm)" (*Seinfeld* Season 6 Episode 21) the phrase in question is used in the following context:

Kramer, one of the show's characters, is gambling with a stranger, and he's down by some amount. Kramer proposes a "double or nothing" final bet, which is accepted. Kramer ends up winning that bet... and it's later shown that he walks away *with a cheque*.

I don't get this. Given the definition of "[double or nothing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_or_nothing)", how is he walking away with anything at all? Isn't the idea that his previous debt should be merely cleared upon winning?

Comment: I recall the same problem (Kramer's DON win) with an episode of Fresh Prince of Bel Air, which added to my childhood confusion.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it would be a better fit on Movies&TV.SE

Comment: (a) It's a question about the English expression, not the show. (b) Migration is not the same thing as closure. Flag it for mod action, rather than voting to close.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the asker does understand the English language expression (it's asked and answered), any confusion arises from misunderstanding the context of the Seinfeld episode. As such, this is a plot explanation question which would be on-topic on Movie.SE. With the question to old for migration, it should be closed here as there is no English language problem.

Comment: It remains a question about the English expression and it's asked-and-answered because it was open, allowing for it to be answered. There may be nothing else for other editors to add, but that doesn't make it an off-topic question. Incidentally, if you feel terribly strongly on the topic [old posts can still be migrated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258349/can-or-cant-questions-be-migrated-after-60-days). It's just rare to avoid disruptions. This low-vote post certainly wouldn't be one, though.

Comment: That's pretzel logic.

Comment: @lly By 'asked and answered', I meant that the answer (to the English language issue) is already contained in the question: *"the idea that his previous debt should be merely cleared upon winning"*. Ironically, this question also attracted a wrong answer, not because users don't understand the English language expression; but because they have not seen or do not accurately recall the events in the episode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not wrong about the expression. "[Double or nothing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/double_or_nothing)" means doubling or canceling the existing debt. In this case, the $3200 Kramer has already lost betting on airport arrivals would either become nothing if he wins the next bet or $6400 if he loses. (Within the show itself, he wouldn't've actually paid that amount even if he had lost: he would've forfeited his collateral, a valuable bag of mail that [Newman](https://seinfeld.fandom.com/wiki/Newman) had previously stolen from [David Berkowitz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Berkowitz)'s route.)

You're wrong about two different aspects of the episode itself. First, there's a time skip.

> Earl: I should've quit at double or nothing.

That is, he *didn't* quit at the double or nothing bet on the Ithaca plane arrival. He continued to bet (and lose) off camera. Second, Kramer doesn't walk away with anything. Because Elaine shows up and reveals that Kramer's friend Jerry was personally responsible for the late Ithaca plane that got Kramer out of his hole, Earl Hafler refuses to pay for his own loses (which he had begun doing in [traveler's checks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/traveller%27s_cheque), rather than with an [actual check](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/cheque)).

In other words, [the bet ends up finishing at "nothing" after all](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/StatusQuoisGod).

Comment: Would the downvoter mind explaining what could be improved in this answer? or, mods, are you able remove such an obviously malicious one, assuming this comes from a serial downvoter?

Comment: This is a great answer, but I agree that it belongs on https://movies.stackexchange.com

Comment: Great answer. :) Downvoters: f*** off and find something better to do.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, "double or nothing" means a doubling of the debt or a cancelation of the debt. If the debtor wins the bet, the debt is canceled.

I'm not familiar with that Seinfeld episode, but I believe the purpose of the show was to be funny, not necessarily to make sense.

Comment: Agreed on all counts. Given the nature of Kramer it would not surprise me if he walked away with the double and more. Nothing ever affects him badly.

Comment: Stupid stuff like this happens on shows all the time.  Quite annoying.